# Automatically wake and sleep device on timer

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, tasker, standby

I have a vanilla Android tablet running Jelly Bean 4.2.2 with root access. I've set this tablet up as a photo frame using daydream. Is there a way via settings or an app that can automatically sleep the device or display at a certain time and then wake it back up at a different specified time?

Comment: Explore an app called [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). You can also check out its tutorials and guide to know how.

Comment: While I second Narayanan (I'm using *Tasker* myself), there are multiple automation solutions available in the playstore. *Tasker* is worth every cent, but there are also free solutions like e.g. [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic) or [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) which might be capable of that. Check the related section on their playstore pages for more :)

Comment: Guys, please consider posting these comments as answers, so they can be upvoted, and so the question will stop showing as unanswered. You've both been on the site long enough to know the comment box isn't for half-assed answers.